# AdonisJs migrations solution for many to many

Tags: node.js, database, types, migration, adonis.js

I was wondering how I can solve a many to many solutions with migrations like at this diagram:
[DB relation diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqo9m.png)

u_id_user is a FK from the User table

u_g_id is unique and auto-increment

g_id_group is a FK from Group

Code example:

```
class UserGroupsSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('user_groups', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('u_id_user')
      table.integer("g_id_group")
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }
```

An other problem is that if I run my migrations it creates the tables with type MyISAM and I cant build relations with this type.. so how can I change the default type to InnoDB?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's not good to mix your questions, you can also change the storage engine to InnoDB manually as it depends on your database configuration. I haven't found a way to do this from adonis

Answer (score 0):

From the adonis.js [documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/relationships#_belongs_to_many) you need to define your models like this:

```
const Model = use('Model')

class User extends Model {
  groups () {
    return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Group')
  }
}

module.exports = User
```

After that you can query the date like this:

```
const user = await User.find(1)

const groups = await user
  .groups()
  .wherePivot('user_id', '=', user.id)
  .fetch()
```

I haven't tested the code but this should put you on the right track